# Strange classes passed from MATLAB to Java

Tags: java, matlab

I have some MATLAB code and some Java code that need to talk with each other. I was getting a `NoSuchMethodError`. When I pass a MATLAB double array to a Java method that accepts `double[]` argument.

So I write a simple "hello world" to get the class of an object passed to the method

```
public void printArray(Object array) {

        System.out.println(array.getClass());
        System.out.println(array.getClass().getPackage());
    }
```

Calling this method from MATLAB, I get this interesting output:

```
>> a.printArray(2)
class java.lang.Double
package java.lang
>> a.printArray('hello')
class java.lang.String
package java.lang
>> a.printArray(true)
class java.lang.Boolean
package java.lang
>> a.printArray([2 3 4])
class [D
null
>> a.printArray([true false])
class [Z
null
```

Can someone explain whats happening. I have MATLAB R14 and the Java class is compiled with 1.3 compatibility.

Comment: Seems like expected behavior... the arrays are of primitive booleans and doubles. Could you perhaps describe the code that gives you the NoSuchMethodError exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the original problem has been [updated by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464216/strange-classes-passed-from-matlab-to-java#466400), so I'll take the chance to summarize our findings so far:

- We have established that the sample code in the original question produces the expected behavior. **MATLAB passes data as primitives to Java, and Java performs the appropriate autoboxing to Objects.** As pointed out in [Matthew Simoneau's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464216/strange-classes-passed-from-matlab-to-java#466086), MATLAB explains how it matches its data types to Java data types in the "[Passing Data to a Java Method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-data-to-a-java-method.html)" section of its documentation. The surprising thing is that a single MATLAB data type may match different Java data types, e.g. `logical` matches `boolean`, `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, and `double`, in that order of precedence.
- The `NoSuchMethodError` that the OP initially encountered was caused by the use of a wrong method. This is [no longer a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464216/strange-classes-passed-from-matlab-to-java#466400). **Using `double[]` as the method argument works.**
- **The "strange" class names (`[D` and `[Z`) are actually notations used by Java to describe arrays of primitive types.** The API explains the usage in [Class.getName()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()).

Case closed =)

Answer (score 2):

Looks simple to me: Matlab passes numbers to Java as Double instances, strings as String instances, booleans as Boolean instances, and arrays as Java arrays. So try changing your method signature from `method(double[] blah)` to `method(Double[] blah)`.

Comment: I don't know if this is indeed the case... I think MATLAB passes them as primitives, and Java autoboxes them to Objects. Unfortunately, autoboxing doesn't apply to arrays. That means only method(double[] blah) would work.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB has a set of heuristics to convert MATLAB data types to the type required by the Java method being called.  The full details are described in [Passing Data to a Java Method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-data-to-a-java-method.html) in the MATLAB documentation.

The method's signature, `void printArray(Object array)`, doesn't give MATLAB much information about what Java really wants.  This is why you're seeing a variety of types, depending on how you call it.

With respect to your original question, I'm not sure why this wouldn't be working for you.  Give a close look at [Passing Built-In Types](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-data-to-a-java-method.html#f61465).

It gives the sample MATLAB code

```
poly = java.awt.Polygon([14 42 98 124], [55 12 -2 62], 4);
```

where the corresponding Java method has the signature

```
public Polygon(int xpoints[], int ypoints[], int npoints)
```

This is a little different than your question because it involves arrays of ints rather than arrays of doubles, but should work identically.

Comment: Those links are broke. This is the working version of the first one: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-data-to-a-java-method.html

Answer (score 0):

Apperantly java accepts the array quite fine. Its the Arrays.toString() method that fails to work on that input. I used double[] in the method signature and printed the array in a loop, and it worked. However it is still an open question as to why the strange class names apear.

Comment: It would be great if you could incorporate your response in the original question, instead of creating a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it's the expected behaviour. Java arrays just don't have a very useful string representation. If you want to get a more useful string representation of your arrays, you could wrap them in a List, like:

```
Arrays.asList(new Double[] { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3 })
```